# Room Create Table with Index

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am migrating my Room database. I want to add new table. So I created the Entry class like this:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = Project.class,
    parentColumns = "projectId",
    childColumns = "projectId",
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)},
    indices = {
            @Index(name = "projectId_index", value = {"projectId"})
    })
public class ProjectDimension {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long dimensionId;

    @ColumnInfo
    private long projectId;

    @ColumnInfo
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo
    private String value;

    // getters and setters here...
}
```

Then my Dao looks like this:

```
@Dao
public interface ProjectDimensionDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ProjectDimension")
    Single<List<ProjectDimension>> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ProjectDimension WHERE projectId = :projectId")
    Single<List<ProjectDimension>> getByProject(long projectId);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insert(ProjectDimension projectDimension);

    @Delete
    void delete(ProjectDimension projectDimension);
}
```

Then lastly on my database class:

```
@Database(entities = {
    Contact.class,
    ContactEmail.class,
    ContactPhone.class,
    Monitoring.class,
    Organization.class,
    OrgEmail.class,
    OrgPhone.class,
    Project.class,
    ProjectContact.class,
    ProjectLocation.class,
    ProjectDimension.class
}, version = 2)
public abstract class MonitoringDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static MonitoringDatabase instance;

    // other Data Access Objects (DAO) here...
    public abstract ProjectDimensionDao projectDimensionDao();

    public static MonitoringDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    MonitoringDatabase.class, "monitoring-database")
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                        .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Upgrade database from version 1 to 2.
     * Details: Added new table named ProjectDimension
     */
    private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            // create ProjectDimension table
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `ProjectDimension` (`dimensionId` INTEGER, `projectId` INTEGER, " +
                    "`name` TEXT, `value` TEXT, " +
                    "PRIMARY KEY(`dimensionId`), " +
                    "FOREIGN KEY(`projectId`) REFERENCES `Project`(`projectId`) ON DELETE CASCADE)");
        }
    };

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        instance = null;
    }
}
```

After I run it, I got an error that looks like this:

```
Expected:
TableInfo{name='ProjectDimension', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, value=Column{name='value', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, projectId=Column{name='projectId', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, dimensionId=Column{name='dimensionId', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='Project', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[projectId], referenceColumnNames=[projectId]}], indices=[Index{name='projectId_index', unique=false, columns=[projectId]}]}

Found:
TableInfo{name='ProjectDimension', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, value=Column{name='value', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, projectId=Column{name='projectId', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, dimensionId=Column{name='dimensionId', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='Project', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[projectId], referenceColumnNames=[projectId]}], indices=null}
```

I think the problem is in my CREATE statement. I've been searching for the proper SQL query for this but still failed to find some. Somebody help!

Comment: Focus on `indices`, you can reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48940238/2423899 and https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/previews/the-dao-of-entities

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 errors, one regarding the NOT NULL column property, the other regarding foreign keys.

Here are the differences :

Expected :

> projectId notNull=**true**
>
> dimensionId notNull=**true**
>
> foreignKeys indices=**[Index{name='projectId_index', unique=false, columns=[projectId]}]}**

Found

> projectId notNull=**false**
>
> dimensionId notNull=**false**
>
> foreignKeys indices=**null**

I can help with the first problem, in your Entity, the type `long` can't be nullable. Change it to `Long` to make it work.

For the second one, add something like this to your migrate function

```
database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX projectId_index ON Project (projectId)");
```

Comment: the table-creation query might not match the generated abstraction layer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annonate projectId as @nonNull annotation.